# Write packets captured with scapy sniff in time intervals

Tags: python, scapy, tcpdump

I’m trying to dump packets to a file captured by scapy `sniff` function every 10 second to no avail.

That is possible with tcpdump like: `tcpdump -s 0 -i <interface> -G 10 -w <output.pcap>`.
`G` flag is the rotate_seconds.

Is this achievable with scapy?

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is.  Have a look at the `wrpcap()` documentation.

Essentially, you will simply build a callback function that receives packets and takes actions.  Here's a very simple example that is not necessarily intended to be functional. (I'm writing it on the fly here)  This should save a cap file every 100 packets.  You would simply need to change the logic to be time based instead of packet count based.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from scapy import sniff

pendingPackets = []
baseFilename = "capture-"
totalPackets = 0

def handle_packet(packet):
    pendingPackets.append(packet)
    totalPackets += 1

    if len(pendingPackets) >= 100:
        filename = baseFilename + str(totalPackets) + ".pcap"
        wrpcap(filename, pendingPackets)
        pendingPackets = []

sniff(filter="ip", prn=handle_packet)
```

Comment: I didn't want to use sniff callback function. I thought that there would be something similar to  tcpdump `-G` flag.
I'm using a multi threading approach, so, a time based logic in my case is a bit tricky though. Thanks.

Comment: You might not like it but this is the only way to do it. :)

Comment: And, frankly, multithreaded or not, writing based on time rather than packet count is a very simple change given the code above.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I suffered packet loss using scapy callback. Pure tcpdump did the cut.
It's a good solution though. Thanks.